# Misfitting of drift rate in Wiener model

Tags: r, experiment-design, item-response-theory, psychology

In a binary-decision experiment, the accuracy and response time of some subjects were recorded. My goal is to fit a Wiener model to response time and accuracy data. The binary experiment has three conditions and the drift rate  (delta) can vary between these conditions.

The data is uploaded. Let's take a look at the mean of response time

```
load("dat.rdata")
require(ggplot2)
agg <- aggregate(q~condition, data=dat, FUN=mean)
colnames(agg)[2] <- "Mean"

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = condition, y = Mean), data = agg)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill = condition)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = condition, y =  Mean + .05, label = round(Mean, 3)))+
  ggtitle("Response Time By Condition")+
  ylab("Mean of Response Time") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

So, condition 3 has the slowest response time. Now let's fit the model using the [RWiener](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWiener/index.html) package

```
many_drifts <- function(x, datlist) {
l = 0
 for (c in 1:length(datlist)) {
    l = l + wiener_deviance(x[c(1, 2, 3, c+3)], datlist[[c]])
 }
 return(l)
}
cond1 <- dat[dat[, "condition"] == 1, -3]
cond2 <- dat[dat[, "condition"] == 2, -3]
cond3 <- dat[dat[, "condition"] == 3, -3]
datlist <- list(cond1, cond2, cond3)
res <- nlm(p=c(1, .1, .5, 1, 1, 1), f=many_drifts, datlist)
```

and plot the drift rate by condition:

```
drift <- data.frame(condition = as.factor(c(1, 2, 3)), drift = res$estimate[4:6])
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = condition, y = drift), data = drift)+
   geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill = condition)) + 
   geom_text(aes(x = condition, y =  drift + .05, label = round(drift, 3)))+
   ggtitle("Drift Rate  By Condition")+
   ylab("Drift Rate") +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

So, here is a paradox: the drift rate for the slowest experiment is the highest! But it shouldn't be like that. Generally, I have 10 persons and the same paradox came up even when I used a Bayesian (diffusion) model and sampled from posterior distribution in JAGS.

I dont know how to explain it?
I would appreciate any help.

P.S.
data as CSV
http://www.wikiupload.com/9LVT07H5QMVAGM4

ASCII
http://www.wikiupload.com/7QUUCG8HJHWUZ8D

or rdata.
http://www.wikiupload.com/PT9W36EP10PRPN4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if the driftrate is higher, the response times should be faster. This is so, as with a higher driftrate, the model should be faster in hitting the boundary towards the driftrate leads it.

So the drifrate estimates of your data do make sense to me.

A simple example to illustrate this point is given in the R script below:

```
# data 
library("RWiener")
c1 <- cbind(rwiener(500,2,.3,.5,0), condition=1)
c2 <- cbind(rwiener(500,2,.3,.5,2), condition=2)
c3 <- cbind(rwiener(500,2,.3,.5,5), condition=3)
dat <- rbind(c1,c2,c3)

# plot means
x11()
require(ggplot2)
agg <- aggregate(q~condition, data=dat, FUN=mean)
colnames(agg)[2] <- "Mean"

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = condition, y = Mean), data = agg)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill = condition)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = condition, y =  Mean + .05, label = round(Mean, 3)))+
  ggtitle("Response Time By Condition")+
  ylab("Mean of Response Time") +
  theme_bw() 

# estimate driftrates
many_drifts <- function(x, datlist) {
l = 0
 for (c in 1:length(datlist)) {
    l = l + wiener_deviance(x[c(1, 2, 3, c+3)], datlist[[c]])
 }
 return(l)
}
cond1 <- dat[dat[, "condition"] == 1, -3]
cond2 <- dat[dat[, "condition"] == 2, -3]
cond3 <- dat[dat[, "condition"] == 3, -3]
datlist <- list(cond1, cond2, cond3)
res <- nlm(p=c(1, .1, .5, 1, 1, 1), f=many_drifts, datlist)

# plot driftrates
x11()
drift <- data.frame(condition = as.factor(c(1, 2, 3)), drift = res$estimate[4:6])
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = condition, y = drift), data = drift)+
   geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill = condition)) + 
   geom_text(aes(x = condition, y =  drift + .05, label = round(drift, 3)))+
   ggtitle("Drift Rate  By Condition")+
   ylab("Drift Rate") +
   theme_bw()
```